# Entity Framework Migration With Spatial Data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, spatial

I'm trying to do a code-first "add-migration" but I am getting the error:

Spatial types and functions are not available for this provider because the assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types' version 10 or higher could not be found.

I understand how to load the spatial DLL in the running app, but how do I do it when running a migration from the package manager?

Edit: OK, it's worse than I throught. This simple console app won't run because of the same error. I have Microsoft.SqlServer.Types installed from NuGet. Whats going on?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
            System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography location = System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography.PointFromText("POINT(" + 10 + " " + 10 + ")", 4326);
        }
```

Exception: Spatial types and functions are not available for this provider because the assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types' version 10 or higher could not be found.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I got it working. There was something wrong with my environment. I uninstalled everything "SQL server" related on my system, installed VS 2017, installed "System CLR Types for Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012" and the error went away.

Not sure which thing fixed it, but if you're having the same issue, try uninstalling all "CLR Types for Microsoft® SQL Server" and try installing the latest.

Comment: In my case, I installed 64 bit version of CLR types as SQL server 2012 was 64 bit but it didn't work. Then I installed 32 bit version considering visual studio is 32 bit. Still didn't work. Uninstalled both versions and installed 32 bit version again and It worked finally.

Answer (score -1):

Try to install `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` from the Package Manager console:

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.SqlServer.Types
```

Comment: Already did but it did not help. When you add this package, it tells you to load the spatial DLL at run-time with a provided routine. Not sure how to do the same when running add-migration?